# Facebook Like Box - Controlling What Appears in the Stream

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox

Anyone know of a way to control way appears in the Like Box Stream. By default it seems to be all page actions including photo album updates. Is there a way to control this to show just posts for example?

Comment: I do have a plugin for iframe which does the same, which i often customize for people.
here are two examples:
all public posts to your page 
https://anotherfeed.com/?doc=feed&pid=anotherfeed&type=feed
page only posts
https://anotherfeed.com/?doc=posts&pid=anotherfeed&type=posts
if they can be useful to you project, i can custom filter to show only the type of posts you wish to display.  just send me a message on facebook.  http://facebook.com/shawnsspace

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no documented way to control the feed content of the like box.